# Golang Google Admin Directory API - can't set ChangePasswordAtNextLogin to false

Tags: go, google-api

I'm trying to use Go and the Google Admin Directory API to manage some Gsuite user attributes, specifically passwords and changePasswordAtNextLogin. I can build my user and send it to update

```
srv := client()
user := admin.User{
    ChangePasswordAtNextLogin: forceReset,
    HashFunction:              "MD5",
    Password:                  fmt.Sprintf("%x", md5.Sum([]byte(newPassword))),
}

_, err := srv.Users.Update(email, &user).Do()
```

and the password will be updated successfully. If `forceRest` is `true` then it will set the flag for the user, but if it's `false` it won't remove the flag! Is this a bug in the Go API library, or am I doing something wrong?

I tried adding `ForceSendFields: []string{"ChangePasswordAtNextLogin"}` to the `User` struct and that didn't help.

Comment: I have a feeling that structure is being marshalled as a JSON with an `omitempty` flag on that field.  The json package omits false booleans as if they are nil: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13284

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the case. There's a similar issue to this one on the GitHub [issues page](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/issues/229) for google-api-go-client, so I commented there.